# How to enable/disable inputs in blazor

Tags: html, blazor, disabled-input

I am trying to `Enable/Disable` a group of `time` inputs in Blazor based on a `checkbox` ;  while for `inputs` of type `button` the below solution works ,for inputs of type `time` it doesn't :

Solution for button input that works:

```
<button type="button" class="@this.SetButton"></button>

[Parameter] public bool state { get; set; }

public string SetButton() {
    string result = state ? "" : "disabled";
    return result;
}
```

Attempt for time inputs that does not work:

```
<input bind="@IsDisabled" type="checkbox" />                      
<input class="@this.GetGroupState()" type="time" />

protected bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

public string GetGroupState() {
    return this.IsDisabled ? "disabled" : "";
}
```

P.S.: In the first scenario the `bool` comes as a parameter from another `component` so I don't bind it. In the second case, however, it is bound to the `checkbox`.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

To disable elements you should use the [disabled attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp).

I've modified your code a bit and this will do what you're after. Blazor will automatically add or remove the `disabled` attribute based on the `IsDisabled` value.

You should use the disabled attribute on your button as well. It's a much better practice.

```
<button type="button" disabled="@IsDisabled"></button>
<input @bind="IsDisabled" type="checkbox" />

<input disabled="@IsDisabled" type="time" />

@code{
    protected bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
}
```

You can still combine this with applying a CSS class for styling the disabled element. It's up to you.

Comment: Yes, Blazor makes `disabled="false"` disappear. Takes a little getting used to.

Comment: this answer is certainly correct- i just want to point out that using disabled attributes is not a safe way to prevent form data from being edited or saved as users can easily modify the html client side to remove the disabled attribute then modify the field

Comment: @GregH is correct, you should render your control as a non-editable element, like a label if it is disabled, this will prevent client side fiddling.

Comment: @Sergey Fixed. Just for any future readers, it actually doesn't matter if you use quotes or not around variables in attributes. You're not writing HTML its Razor. So `disabled="@IsDisabled"` and `disabled=@IsDisabled` are both perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks Chris, dunno why I didn't just try it, tried everything but.  I had no idea that when false, Blazor made the attribute go-away :-)  been scratching my head for hours trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: If you get a "is not a valid value" warning, that's just a bug of Blazor 3.x, see here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/16833

Comment: I'm sure I'm abusing HTML, but I've got an @onclick on an <li> and disabling this doesn't seem to work.  Is it only buttons and inputs that can be disabled in Blazor?

Comment: @Uxonith Disabled only works if the element does something that can be disabled, like a click. li’s don’t have a action function they are just a way of displaying something. I’d put a button in your li and remove the OnClick. It’s best not to mess with HTML semantics for the sake of accessibility and such.

Comment: Kind of obvious in hind sight but in case it helps anyone get past a brain fart: A string value of "false" won't work, it's got to be a boolean.

Comment: For net 6 (I guess net5 too), this part should be rewritten: `bind = "@IsDisabled"` as `@bind = "IsDisabled"`

Comment: Don't forget you might need to call `StateHasChanged()` after changing the bool value that drives the `Disabled` state of the input/button.

Answer (score 16):

Quotes can make all the difference, or at least during server prerendering:

a) Without quotes - The disable parameter will be removed when it's evaluated as false. This will work as expected:

```
<input disabled=@(IsDisabled) ...
```

b) With quotes - It will add a value of "True" or "False" to the parameter eg. `disabled="True"` or `disabled="False"`. It will remain disabled as the browser is on the hunt for the parameter rather than a value.

```
<input disabled="@(IsDisabled)" ...
```

Answer (score 15):

There is an alternative way you can achieve this.

```
<fieldset disabled=@ShouldBeDisabled>
  Your input controls in here will be disabled/enabled by the browser
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also get the value to disable the button directly as an expression

```
<input disabled="@(MyCondition ? true : false)" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: What is the purpose of true : false? Isnt that the value of MyCondition to begin with?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the point of the ternary operator.  Just `@MyCondition` should be fine.

Comment: Great example of code for codes sake. You basically wrote `If(MyCondition == true) { return true; } else { return false; }`. I would suggest you delete this answer, but for some reason you have some upvotes, god only knows how...

Comment: no button referenced in the code either...

Answer (score 4):

With the reference of the above answer `a) Without Quotes`

```
<input disabled=@(IsDisabled) ...
```

Incase you set  `IsDisabled` to `true`, the above line will not disable the input

This solves by adding `!IsDisabled`

```
Blazor Input Control
```

<InputText @bind-Value="UserModel.UserName" id="userName" class="form-control" disabled=@(!IsDisabled) />

```
HTML Input Control
```

<input disabled=@(!IsDisabled) ...

Answer (score 4):

Adding disabled is not really a good solution because the client can inspect the page and remove the `disabled` attribute. I think the best solution is to add disabled and remove the two way binding by using `value` instead of `@bind`.

```
@if (IsDisabled)
{
    <input type="checkbox" value="@Value" disabled />
}
else
{
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="Value" />
}
```

Now even if the user removes the `disabled` attribute the value can be changed but it won't be updated.

I prefer to put all my input components into their own component that inherits `InputBase` for two way binding while handling `IsDisabled` as described.

Answer (score 1):

Blazor makes disabled="false" disappear.  This statement is not true! The only way is to use if statement like this.

```
@if (IsDisabled)
{
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="Value" disabled />
}
else
{
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="Value" />
}
```

Comment: Should be @bind = "IsDisabled"

Comment: @Sith2021 you are totally not following this entire discussion. They are talking about adding the `disabled` attribute to a HTML element.

Comment: @Vesko Use `@value` instead of `@bind` on the disabled input to prevent client side manipulation as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75562491/591285).

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified the complete code - Working!

```
Test Cases:
By default checkbox is unchecked, and submit button is disabled.
When checkbox checked, submit button enabled
When checkbox un-checked, submit button disabled
```

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Final Submission</div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="form-check">
            <input id="xbrlfinal" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" bind="@IsAcknowledged" 
            @onchange="@((args) => IsAcknowledged = (bool)args.Value)">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                I hereby declare that I have checked and verified.
            </label>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Main Card body ends -->
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-md-3" @onclick="OnSubmissionProcess" disabled="@(IsAcknowledged?false:true)">Process</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Main Card ends -->
```

```
 protected bool IsAcknowledged { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML disabled property cannot get value true or false. Only way is add it or not: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Comment: This answer is quite misleading since Blazor works a little differently when it comes to handling HTML attributes. Consider having a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69016913/6877769

Comment: It's not misleading, it's simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me neither of these worked

```
<input disabled="@(IsDisabled)" type="radio" />
<input disabled=@(IsDisabled) type="radio" />
```

I had to remove the quotes and the braces, and this finally worked

```
<input disabled=@IsDisabled type="radio" />
```