# Blazor: How to use the onchange event in <select> when using @bind also?

Tags: select, bind, onchange, blazor

I need to be able to run a function after a selection in made in a `<select>`.  The issue is I'm also binding with @bind and I get a error when I try to use @onchange stating that it is already in use by the @bind.  I tried using @onselectionchange, but that does nothing(doesn't run the function).  I could forget the @bind and just assign @onchange to a function, but I'm not sure how to pass the selected value to the function.

I have the following code:

```
<select @bind="@SelectedCustID" @ @onchange="@CustChanged" class="form-control">
    @foreach (KeyGuidPair i in CustList)
    {
        <option value="@i.Value">@i.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: just a side note: you can use `@bind=SelectedCustID` instead of `@bind="@SelectedCustID"`. its much cleaner :)

Comment: One character `@ ` seems to be redundant.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452319/in-blazor-how-to-bind-and-then-fire-onchange-in-a-dynamic-model/64783149#64783149

Answer (score 54):

`@bind` is essentially equivalent to the having both `value` and `@onchange`, e.g.:

```
<input @bind="CurrentValue" />
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<input value="@CurrentValue" @onchange="@((ChangeEventArgs e) => CurrentValue = e.Value.ToString())" />
```

Since you've already defined `@onchange`, instead of also adding `@bind`, just add `value` to prevent the clash:

```
<select value="@SelectedCustID" @onchange="@CustChanged" class="form-control">
    @foreach (KeyGuidPair i in CustList)
    {
        <option value="@i.Value">@i.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Just to mention you explanation where you said "is equivalent to" has helped me figure out how to pass multiple parameters on the onchange event of a blazor select . Thank you.

Answer (score 48):

```
<select @bind="MyProperty">
<option>Your Option<option>
</select>

@code  {
    private string myVar;

    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set
        {
            myVar = value;
            SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: this works but will be a problem if you need to do some asyn call, a database update for example....

Comment: @Alexandre, I think you can convert an an asynchronous call to synchronous by using `.Wait()`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: It should be select not input as user asked for select code.

Comment: Invoke the event rather than calling a method to keep setter „lean”. Then You can use async void and update state manually at the end with StateHasChanged()

Answer (score 18):

Just add `@bind-value` and `@bind-value:event="oninput"` with `@onchange` as below. Note the lower case letters. This works for me without any issue.

```
<select @bind-value="variablenametokeepselectedvalue" @onchange="yourmethodname" @bind-value:event="oninput">
 <option value="1">Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 14):

This seems to be a popular confusion. Firstly you cant use `@onchange` since it would internally be used by `@bind`. You should be able to access the selected value from the setter of your `CustChanged` property. Based on what you are trying to do with your `CustChanged`, you may not even need to manually check when this value is updated. For instance, if your intent is to use `CustChanged` in your UI directly or indirectly (within Linq or something), the UI would automatically update with `CustChanged` value when your `<select>` is changed. Hence, for most use cases I don't see the need to check when it was updated.

To use `@onchange`, you can bind it to a function something like this:

```cs
public void OnUpdated(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = e.Value;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question asked.

Comment: annoyingly this seems to actually give the option text selected, not the option value

Answer (score 14):

Starting from [.NET 7 Preview 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-7/#blazor-data-binding-get-set-after-modifiers), the recommended way to handle this issue is to use the `bind:after` modifier.

Here is a small example (partially borrowed from the docs):

```
<p>
    <label>
        Select one or more cities:
        <select @bind="SelectedCities" multiple @bind:after="DoSomething">
            <option value="bal">Baltimore</option>
            <option value="la">Los Angeles</option>
            <option value="pdx">Portland</option>
            <option value="sf">San Francisco</option>
            <option value="sea">Seattle</option>
        </select>
    </label>
</p>

<span>
    Selected Cities: @string.Join(", ", SelectedCities)
</span>

@code {
    public string[] SelectedCities { get; set; } = new[] { "bal", "sea" };

    // Run your logic here after a binding event
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', SelectedCities));
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting from .Net 7 was the key. Using latest .Net Core made all previous answers invalid it seems. @bindafter works. Thanks Jesse.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid `@bind` altogether (if you're using a `foreach`):

```
<select @onchange=@(handleChange)>
    @foreach (var option in _options){
        <option value=@option.Id selected=@(SelectedId == option.Id)>@option.Name</option>
    }
</select>

@code {
    public record Person(int Id, string Name);
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public List<Person> _options = new List<Person>() {
        new Person(1,"A"),
        new Person(2,"B"),
        new Person(3,"C")
    };

    public void handleChange(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Value);
        SelectedId = Int32.Parse(args.Value.ToString());
    }

}
```

---

Some sordid details: I was getting some weird behavior when trying to use F# with server-side Blazor. In short, setting the `List` of options to the result of an Entity Framework query (mapped to a list of records) wouldn't `@bind` properly, but using a dummy list of options that were C# classes and not F# records *did* work. It wasn't due to it being records though, because if I set the list to the EF query and then immediately set it to a dummy list of records, it still didn't `@bind` properly - but it *did* work if I commented out the EF line.

Comment: true or false to selected attribute is not valid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033944/what-values-can-appear-in-the-selected-attribute-of-the-option-tag

Comment: @Alexandre True. However, Blazor converts the `selected=true/false` to valid HTML. https://i.imgur.com/QEDQceP.png

The same works for other attributes too, like `disabled`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002514/how-to-enable-disable-inputs-in-blazor also https://blazor-university.com/components/code-generated-html-attributes/

Comment: Hi DharmaTurlte could you please elaborate on the @onchange=@(x => ...). What purpose has the lambda expression.  What code do I have to write there (a Methode Call? How?). Thx

Comment: @nogood I filled in the lambda. LMK if you're still confused.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this example. It is using **@bind** but upon setting the value it triggers **@onchange** event

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="client">Client Name</label>
    <select id="client" @bind="CheckSelected" class="form-control">
       <option value="selected1">selected1</option>
       <option value="selected2">selected2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
@code {

    private string selectedItem {get; set;}

    private string CheckSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            ChangeEventArgs selectedEventArgs = new ChangeEventArgs();
            selectedEventArgs.Value = value;
            OnChangeSelected(selectedEventArgs);
        }
    }

    private void OnChangeSelected(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            selectedItem = e.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Worth to notice this solution works with blazor `EditForm` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756167/onchange-event-not-firing-blazor-inputselect), as `InputSelect` does not bind event properly in a following way:
`<InputSelect Id="Source" @bind-Value="@model.Source" Class="form-control" @onchange="HandleSourceOptionChanged">`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0), this is their preferred way of handling this problem:

```
<InputText Value="@NewPaymentAmount" class="mdl-textfield__input"
           ValueExpression="() => NewPaymentAmount"
           ValueChanged="(string value) => ValidateAmount(value)" />



private void ValidateAmount(string amount)
{
    NewPaymentAmount = amount;
    
    // Do validation or whatever
}
```

Or the `async` way:

```
<InputText Value="@NewPaymentAmount" class="mdl-textfield__input"
           ValueExpression="() => NewPaymentAmount"
           ValueChanged="async (string value) => await ValidateAmountAsync(value)" />



private async Task ValidateAmountAsync(string amount)
{
    NewPaymentAmount = amount;
    
    // Do validation or whatever
}
```

Comment: No need to await inside `ValueChanged` as this creates a useless state machine. When the code that actually invokes `ValueChanged` wants to await the return value it can do it no matter if it is awaited also in the `ValueChanged` method body.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed in order to get it working with validation also!

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code for reference how we use select tag with bind value and call function onselection value change in blazor

```
<InputSelect class="form-control mb-0" ValueExpression="@(()=>request.Id)" Value="request.Id" 
ValueChanged="@((string value) => SelectedValueChange(value))">
@if (dropdownResponses != null)
{
   @foreach (var item in dropdownResponses)
   {
     <option value="@item.Id.ToString()">@item.Name</option>
   }
}
</InputSelect>
```

use `<InputSelect>` tag instead of `<select>` tag and use `ValueChanged` method for getting call on select value change

here is the code of ValueChanged function

```
internal void SelectedValueChange(string value)
{
   string NewValue = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is, if possible, use an EditForm wrapper around your form elements.  Then you can detect a change of any of the form elements, in one place.  This is good for, for example, a bunch of search filters.  Any change in any of the filters should trigger another query of the data, etc.

Example of how to trigger event on form changes is here:

[blazor editform change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576373/blazor-editform-change-events)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="client">Client Name</label>
    <select class="form-control" @onchange="@((e) => { myVar = e.Value.ToString(); MyMethod(); })">
       <option value="val1">val1</option>
       <option value="val2">val2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is how I was able to set the property while calling for a method in the @onchange event.

-Blazor Server
-Dotnet Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I use `oninput` to essentially have `bind` and `onchange`.

`oninput` triggers when the input value is changed whereas bind/onchange triggers when the element loses focus and the input has changed.

This might not fit every scenario however as it wll trigger on every input while typing, depending on your need or for inputs such as selects, radios, etc. it should be suitable.