# In Blazor, How to @bind and then fire @onchange in a dynamic model

Tags: c#, blazor

Model:

```
public class FiltersModel
{      
    public CheckBoxListWithTitle Brand { get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxListWithTitle
{        
    public List<FilterCheckBox> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
}

public class FilterCheckBox
{        
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

Razor:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Brand.CheckBoxes)
{
<label>
    @item.Value
    <input type="checkbox" @onchange="@FilterChangedBrand" />  
</label>
}
```

@code:

```
public FiltersModel Model { get; set; } // Initialized in OnParametersSet

private void FilterChangedBrand(UIChangeEventArgs e)
{
    string newCheckedBrand = e.Value.ToString();
    // Now How to Find and Set the relevant Model property to newCheckedBrand
    FiltersChanged?.Invoke(Model);
}
```

How to Find and Set the relevant Model property to newCheckedBrand in the FilterChangedBrand method.

Or Use @bind="@item.Checked" in the checkbox markup and then raise an event when the checked state for one of checkboxes changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there no way how you can use @bind and @onchange you have to make changes purely in the code. Simplest way for you to do that is to use lambda to capture `item`

Razor

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Brand.CheckBoxes)
{
    <label>
        @item.Value
        <input type="checkbox" @onchange="(e) => FilterChangedBrand(item, e)" />
    </label>
}
```

@code

```
public FiltersModel Model { get; set; } // Initialized in OnParametersSet

public event Action<FiltersModel> FiltersChanged;

private void FilterChangedBrand(FilterCheckBox item, ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // here you do work of @bind
    item.Checked = !item.Checked;
    string newCheckedBrand = e.Value.ToString();
    // Now How to Find and Set the relevant Model property to newCheckedBrand
    FiltersChanged?.Invoke(Model);
}
```

Alternative and more complicated way, which may helps if you want reuse your UI with for example WPF is to place that event cascading in the model itself.

```
public class CheckBoxListWithTitle
{
    private List<FilterCheckBox> items = new List<FilterCheckBox>();
    public IReadOnlyList<FilterCheckBox> CheckBoxes => items.AsReadOnly();

    public event EventHandler ModelChanged;

    public void Add(FilterCheckBox item)
    {
        item.CheckedChanged += this.Item_CheckedChanged;
        this.items.Add(item);
    }

    private void Item_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModelChanged.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class FilterCheckBox
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;
}
```

as you see `CheckBoxListWithTitle` will handle propagation of required events. in Razor you only subscribe to `CheckBoxListWithTitle.ModelChanged`

Answer (score 2):

another option is to use in your bound object the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class RowToApprove : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _approved;
  
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  
    public bool Approved
    {
        get => _approved;
        set
        {
            if (value == _approved) return;
            _approved = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and then in your page, register to ItemOnPropertyChanged event.

```
  item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
```

and do your work there:

```
private void ItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

your item could look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" @bind-value="@(context.Approved)" />
```