# select input in blazor Server side getting option's text as its value onchange event

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a problem binding a select on Server side blazor. The passed on the **onchange** event is the options text(label).
Here is my select element:

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label>Role</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control form-control-sm"
                    placeholder="Role"
                    disabled="@IsReadOnly"
                    @onchange="(e) => RoleChanged(e)">
                        <option value="">Select Role...</option>
                        <option value="Member">Member</option>
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="Pioneer">Pioneer</option>
                        <option value="Retailer">Retailer</option>
            </select>
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Role)" class="row" />
</div>
```

Upon debugging the **RoleChanged** method

[image: Option Text Value]

It gets the option text as Value when the event is triggered. 
Also the client validation is not firing

[image: Client Side Validation]

Comment: Client validation works only with built-in `<Input*` components. or by calling `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor you code to use form components :

```cs
<div class="form-group row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label>Role</label>
            <InputSelect class="form-control form-control form-control-sm"
                    placeholder="Role"
                    disabled="@IsReadOnly" Value="Model.Role" ValueChanged="RoleChanged" ValueExpression="@(() => Model.Role)">
                        <option value="">Select Role...</option>
                        <option value="Member">Member</option>
                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="Pioneer">Pioneer</option>
                        <option value="Retailer">Retailer</option>
            </InputSelect >
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Role)" class="row" />
</div>
```

```cs
// an async method must return Task or ValueTask
private async Task RoleChanged(string value)
{
   // your logic
}
```

Comment: I am doing this while waiting for someone to answer and this actually worked.

Comment: I guess this answer didn't work for you, right ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763542/6152891