# Blazor @bind + @onchange for a select html tag

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to bind an enum value to a select tag and handle an @onchange event at the same time, this is the code:

```
<select @bind="Val" @onchange="OnChange">
  @foreach(var v in Enum.GetValues<MyEnum>())
  {
    <option value="@v">@v</option>  
  }
</select>

@code{
  MyEnum Val = MyEnum.Default;

  void OnChange(){
    Console.WriteLine("Value changed");
  }
}
```

But it is telling me that onchange event is already being used in the @bind, so how can I have an onchange event while binding the value. What is the correct event for  tag change

Comment: @vernou they show some ways but they are very dirty solutions that require a lot of extra code, I am looking for something clean, also I somehow did not find that post even after 20 minutes of searching

Comment: I agree... a lot of dirty solution. I advise you to consult these solutions : [Only `@onchange`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167811/2703673) or [Only `@bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58135444/2703673)

Comment: Just use @onchange and bind it to something like `void selectChanged(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs) => value = Enum.Parse<SomeEnum>((string)changeEventArgs.Value!);`