# How to disable InputRadioGroup?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

Is there a way to disable InputRadioGroup in blazor webassembly?

I tried `<InputRadioGroup Disabled="false">`, but that is obviously not working. Any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable/disable inputs in blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55002514/how-to-enable-disable-inputs-in-blazor)

Comment: @AhmedSbai Definitely not a duplicate of this: `InputRadioGroup` is a Blazor component not an HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `<InputRadioGroup>` in a `<fieldset>` and disable that.

```cs
<fieldset disabled="@true">
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="answer">
        @foreach (var option in Question.Options)
        {
            <label class="me-3 form-check-label">
                <InputRadio class="form-check-input me-1" Value="@option" />
                @option
            </label>
        }
    </InputRadioGroup>
</fieldset>
```

The `<InputRadioGroup>` does not output any HTML. It outputs a CascadingValue `CascadingValue<InputRadioContext>` and its ChildContent only.

[Source Code](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Forms/InputRadioGroup.cs,53)

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the group but you can disable each InputRadio:

```
    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="@CurrentlySelectedAnswer">
        @foreach (Answer a in Answers)
        {
            <p>
                <InputRadio Value="@a.Answer_ID" disabled="@IsReadOnly" />
                @a.Answer_Text
            </p>
        }
    </InputRadioGroup>
```